# Kantu / Selenium selecting from multiselect box

Tags: selenium, webautomation, kantu

I'm using kantu chrome extension to try to enter a form. One of the elements on page is a multi select drop down menu. When I record clicking on it, it gives me:

```
Command: Click
Target: css=#s2id_event_change_new_ical_attributes_calendar_resource_ids > ul
```

but then doesn't record making selections.

I've tried using:

```
command: sendKeys
Target: id=s2id_autogen2
value: room 10 ${KEY_ENTER}
```

which did type "room 10" into the box but for some reason the enter submitted the form without finalizing the field entry. What's funny is when you do it manually you can type "room 10" and hit enter and it enters that field without submitting the form.

Here is the source for the box:

```
 [![<div class="select2-container select2-container-multi" id="s2id_event_change_new_ical_attributes_calendar_resource_ids" 
<ul class="select2-choices">  
<li class="select2-search-choice">
<div>Room 10</div> 
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close icon-remove" tabindex="-1"></a></li>
<li class="select2-search-field">
<label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen2" style="width: 20px;" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-34">
</li></ul></div>][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: any updates on this?